# Error on testing Gingko and Gomega for gingonic, w.Code not working

Tags: go, testing, go-gin, ginkgo, gomega

I have some tests written in Ginkgo that check the return-code, a `502` code should be returned at a specific moment in time, it returns 502 (as you can see on the logs) but the `w.Code` is still `200`.

```
[GIN] 2024/02/06 - 19:08:01 | 502 |   62.918958ms |                 | PUT      "/v1/create-user"
200
```

the code that generated that output is the gin router and this fmt.Printf statement:

(test-code)

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, "/v1/create-user", bytes.NewReader(body))
Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
fmt.Println(w.Code)      // <- this generated the "200"
Ω(w.Code).Should(Equal(502))
```

as you can see, the request returned 502, but the `w.Code` still equals 200. Has any one else had this before? Couldn't find aything online.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found some stuff:

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1120

But I also found out a solution:

It looks like the "error" is with Go's `httptest.ResponseRecorder`. It seems that it can only be written once. In my test-suite, the first test is expected to return `200 OK`, so it sets that value in the response recorder.

This seemed to fix the issue:

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, "/v1/create-user", bytes.NewReader(body))
Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

w := httptest.NewRecorder()  // <- creates a new response recorder

router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
Ω(w.Code).Should(Equal(http.StatusBadGateway))
```

This way the test runs successfully.

Note that i am NOT using `gin.CreateTestContext()`.